# How to register jQuery click handler inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, invision-power-board

The CMS I'm using (Invision Power Board) has nifty Sign In links that when clicked open a dialog instead of changing the page. I found an example of how to create such a link:

```
<a href="..." onmouseover="$( this ).on( \'click\', ipb.global.inlineSignin ); return false;">...</a>
```

The problem is, every time the mouse is moved over the link, the click handler is added. So if I move my mouse over the link ten times and then click it, the Sign In dialog comes up ten times.

I tried changing it to:

```
<a href="..." onclick="ipb.global.inlineSignin; return false;">...</a>
```

But that doesn't work. There aren't any errors in the console, but nothing happens when the link is clicked.

I was able to get this working, but it required some non-inline code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery("a.signIn").on("click", ipb.global.inlineSignin);</script>
```

But that's a problem, because I may have sign in links on different sections of pages (that are generated independently) and if I have the above snippet more than once, then I'm back to the same problem.

Is there any way to make this click handler work using only inline code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the method

```
<a href="..." onclick="ipb.global.inlineSignin(); return false;">...</a>
```